# Accepting application/xml content in webapi controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, frombodyattribute

I want to create an action that will accept application/xml content.

Basically I have created this so far.

```
namespace App.Areas.Test.Controllers
{

    public class UserModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }


    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public UserModel Test([FromBody] UserModel um)
        {
            return um;
        }
    }
}
```

When I post the following content

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <UserModel>
    <FirstName>Some Name</FirstName>
    <LastName>Some Last Name</LastName>
    <Age>30</Age>
    </UserModel>
```

I end up with this response

```
<UserModel i:nil="true" />
```

I tried removing `FromBody` attribute, but that did not help either. For some reason content is not binding to the existing model.

Comment: Your XML document has multiple root element. Might want to wrap it in a `<UserModel>` tag

Comment: you are right. I edited my question, but the response is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do the trick...

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the `Content-Type` : `application\xml` header? You need to inform the serialiser what format the body is in.

Comment: still getting <UserModel i:nil="true" />